# How to validate start date and end date in angular formly

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular8, angular-formly

I have two simple fields (input) of the start date and end date I just want that end date should not be less than the start date

I am using angular 8 
I am using ng module

so from myfile.json file I have created two text fields validated them with my date function (validation.ts) in HTML formly code is there

now I want to validate two dates I am new angular developer please help

```
json code
{
              "className": "col-md-6 col-xs-12",
              "key": "graduationstartdate",
              "type": "input",
              "templateOptions": {
                "label": "Course start Date",
                  "appearance": "outline"

              }
            },

            {
              "className": "col-md-6 col-xs-12",
              "key": "graduationenddate",
              "type": "input",
              "templateOptions": {
                "label": "Course End Date",
                "appearance": "outline"
              }
```

```
validation.ts
it contains a function to validate the date
```

```
form.html
contains formly code of form
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve that is using reactive form. You can create a formGroup which will hold all the formcontrols and now create a custom validator and attach it to your form. 
Please go through documentation about usage of custom validator: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular material date picker

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

and go to this section

> Datepicker with min & max validation

here you can add Datepicker with min & max validation.

The other way is you can use a custom validator that will check end date should not be less than the start date

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
  this.formGroup= this.formBuilder.group({
    startDate: [''],
    endDate: ['']
  }, {validator: this.checkDates});  
}
```

If you are getting your values for variable unavailability at a later stage, you can use patchValue or setValue to assign the values to your form controls:

```
this.formGroup.setValue({
  startDate: this.formGorup.startDate;
  endDate: this.formGroup.endDate;
})
```

The custom validator simply checks that the end date is a later date than the startdate and returns null if it is valid, or then a custom validation error:

```
checkDates(group: FormGroup) {
  if(group.controls.endDate.value < group.controls.startDate.value) {
    return { notValid:true }
  }
  return null;
}
```

and then you can display this custom error in template with:

```
<small *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('notValid')">Not valid</small>
```

Also, remember to mark this formgroup in your form tag:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
```